# Render data from async method is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render data from my MongoDB document but I can't figure out why the state is undefined when it's an async function and I'm awaiting it.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            offers: null
        };

        this.getOffers = this.getOffers.bind(this);
        this.renderOffer = this.renderOffer.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(!this.state.offers) {
            this.getOffers();
        }
    }

    async getOffers() {
        let res = await offerService.getAll();
        this.setState({ offers: res });
    }

    renderOffer(product) {
        return (
            <li key={product._id} className="list__item product">
                <h3 className="product__name">{product.title}</h3>
            </li>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Nav />

                <ul className="list">
                    {(this.state.offers && this.state.offers.length > 0) ? (
                        this.state.offers.map(offer => this.renderOffer(this.state.offer))
                    ) : (
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Whenever I load the page, it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`, despite the fact that if I log the output of `res` in `getOffers()` it shows the data. Why is this?

Comment: `this.state.offers.map(offer => this.renderOffer(this.state.offer))` should probably be `this.state.offers.map(offer => this.renderOffer(offer))`

Comment: Well `this.state.offer` is not defined anywhere. Did you mean `this.renderOffer(offer`)`?

Comment: Thank you, that was clumpsy of me. That did the trick!

Comment: @Hamms you should create an answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your `map` call:

```js
this.state.offers.map(offer => this.renderOffer(this.state.offer))
```

You're attempting to use the undefined variable `this.state.offer` rather than your `offer` map variable. What you actually want is:

```js
this.state.offers.map(offer => this.renderOffer(offer))
```